# Lotus Notes, Tabs, & Reference Database

Tags: windows-7, tabs, database, lotus-notes

A colleague is experiencing a problem with Lotus Notes on her computer that I (first line of tech support) cannot replicate and also cannot find a solution to.

My department has 30+ people in it, we all use the same reference database within Lotus Notes 8.5 running on Windows 7  and no one else is experiencing difficulty.

All of us are set up so that when we open Lotus Notes it opens to the Workspace with a display of all our various databases, mail, calendar, etc. from there we open our mail, and the aforementioned reference database, which open into separate tabs.

However, when my colleague opens the ref db, it does one of two things:

1. Opens in the "Home" tab that displays our Workspace and goes away the moment you click away from it OR
2. Opens into its own tab (as it should), but if it opens into its own tab, context help form you open within the database opens in the same tab as the reference database, necessitating a close out to reopen the ref db.

I've checked, and her LN is set to NOT group tabs, so I'm not sure what's going on or how to fix it. Everything I've tried thus far has failed, including trying to open the red db into its own window. When I try the option is unavailable, although it is available on my computer.

As well, and this may or may not be related, instead of a small 'x' on each tab to close them, there is one larger red 'x' in line with the tabs. When you click the red 'x' it closes the active tab. The red 'x' does not go away. This is also different from the others in the department.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated, as I'm out of ideas. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried a reinstall of Lotus?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't experienced this one specifically, but have you checked the target of the shortcut used to launch Notes?

We have notes.ini files stored in the user's network share and most of the time if we encounter anything like this at launch, it's usually down to the shortcut.

Target: "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\notes.exe" "=H:\Apps\Notes\notes.ini"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to cleanup Notes?
first try: Remove from the notes data directory the complete workspace directory and start notes.
second try: remove cache.ndk or cache.dsk from the notes data directory and restart notes.